# in-memory map and sqlite db at the same time?

Tags: android, sqlite, caching, linkedhashmap

I have some key value pairs to store/query. key = 20 char value= 200-500 char. I am evaluating what will be the best caching mechanism in Android with persistence storage.

I am thinking about using Android SQLite database to store the key value pairs + in memory cache using LinkedHashMap:

- limited sized linked hash map provides fast retrieval (it will remove the least accessed entry)
- SQLite database provides persistence

The reason why I use a limited sized hash map is to avoid reading from SQLite database (backed by file system) all the time. However, I also know SQLite is pretty powerful and I can set cache_size to tweak how much data is cached in memory. So not all query will hit the filesystem. Will it screw up the flash memory? 
Any comment/suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: have you made some experience meanwhile? I have the same problem and don't want to harm the flash memory with too much writes/reads